# Update many-to-many table with removed duplicates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three models: `Author`, `Book`, and `BookAuthor`. The `BookAuthor` model represents a many-to-many relationship between `Author` and `Book`, i.e., a book can have multiple authors and a person can write multiple books.

I need to parse a file of books and store the books, authors, and their relationships in a database. I want to remove any duplicate authors from the `Author` model when I save these records. Which means that I need to update the relationships in the `BookAuthor` association object with the deduplicated author IDs.

How would I remove the duplicate authors while preserving the many-to-many relationships between their books?

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, Session, mapped_column, relationship

import pandas as pd


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class BookAuthor(Base):
    __tablename__ = "book_author"
    book_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("book.id"), primary_key=True)
    author_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("author.id"), primary_key=True)
    book: Mapped["Book"] = relationship(back_populates="authors")
    author: Mapped["Author"] = relationship(back_populates="books")


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "book"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(2048))
    authors: Mapped[list["BookAuthor"]] = relationship(back_populates="book")


class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "author"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    first_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(256))
    last_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(256))

    date_of_birth: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=True)
    date_of_death: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=True)

    books: Mapped[list["BookAuthor"]] = relationship(back_populates="author")


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///books.db")

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

books = [
    {
        "title": "Good Omens: The Nice and Accurate Prophecies of Agnes Nutter, Witch",
        "authors": [
            {
                "first_name": "Terry",
                "last_name": "Pratchett",
                "date_of_birth": 1948,
                "date_of_death": 2015,
            },
            {
                "first_name": "Neil",
                "last_name": "Gaiman",
                "date_of_birth": 1960,
                "date_of_death": None,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "title": "American Gods",
        "authors": [
            {
                "first_name": "Neil",
                "last_name": "Gaiman",
                "date_of_birth": 1960,
                "date_of_death": None,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "title": "The Talisman",
        "authors": [
            {
                "first_name": "Stephen",
                "last_name": "King",
                "date_of_birth": 1947,
                "date_of_death": None,
            },
            {
                "first_name": "Peter",
                "last_name": "Straub",
                "date_of_birth": 1943,
                "date_of_death": 2022,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "title": "The Shining",
        "authors": [
            {
                "first_name": "Stephen",
                "last_name": "King",
                "date_of_birth": 1947,
                "date_of_death": None,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "title": "It",
        "authors": [
            {
                "first_name": "Stephen",
                "last_name": "King",
                "date_of_birth": 1947,
                "date_of_death": None,
            },
        ],
    },
]

with Session(engine) as session:
    for book in books:
        book_db = Book(title=book["title"])
        for author in book["authors"]:
            author_db = Author(
                first_name=author["first_name"],
                last_name=author["last_name"],
                date_of_birth=author["date_of_birth"],
                date_of_death=author["date_of_death"],
            )
            book_author = BookAuthor(book=book_db, author=author_db)
            session.add(book_author)

    session.commit()

    book_authors = str(
        session.query(BookAuthor)
        .join(Book)
        .join(Author)
        .with_entities(
            BookAuthor.book_id.label("book_id"),
            BookAuthor.author_id.label("author_id"),
            Author.first_name,
            Author.last_name,
            Author.date_of_birth,
            Author.date_of_death,
            Book.title,
        )
    )

    print(pd.read_sql_query(sql=book_authors, con=engine).to_string(index=False))
```

This outputs the following table:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| book_id | author_id | author_first_name | author_last_name | author_date_of_birth | author_date_of_death |                             book_title                              |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 |         1 | Terry             | Pratchett        |                 1948 |               2015.0 | Good Omens: The Nice and Accurate Prophecies of Agnes Nutter, Witch |
|       1 |         2 | Neil              | Gaiman           |                 1960 |                      | Good Omens: The Nice and Accurate Prophecies of Agnes Nutter, Witch |
|       2 |         3 | Neil              | Gaiman           |                 1960 |                      | American Gods                                                       |
|       3 |         4 | Stephen           | King             |                 1947 |                      | The Talisman                                                        |
|       3 |         5 | Peter             | Straub           |                 1943 |               2022.0 | The Talisman                                                        |
|       4 |         6 | Stephen           | King             |                 1947 |                      | The Shining                                                         |
|       5 |         7 | Stephen           | King             |                 1947 |                      | It                                                                  |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I want:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| book_id | author_id | author_first_name | author_last_name | author_date_of_birth | author_date_of_death |                             book_title                              |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 |         1 | Terry             | Pratchett        |                 1948 |               2015.0 | Good Omens: The Nice and Accurate Prophecies of Agnes Nutter, Witch |
|       1 |         2 | Neil              | Gaiman           |                 1960 |                      | Good Omens: The Nice and Accurate Prophecies of Agnes Nutter, Witch |
|       2 |         2 | Neil              | Gaiman           |                 1960 |                      | American Gods                                                       |
|       3 |         3 | Stephen           | King             |                 1947 |                      | The Talisman                                                        |
|       3 |         4 | Peter             | Straub           |                 1943 |               2022.0 | The Talisman                                                        |
|       4 |         3 | Stephen           | King             |                 1947 |                      | The Shining                                                         |
|       5 |         3 | Stephen           | King             |                 1947 |                      | It                                                                  |
+---------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Duplicate authors are defined as having the same `first_name`, `last_name`, `date_of_birth`, and `date_of_death` attributes.

Note: I need to avoid Python data structures and delegate most of the work to the database itself. The data source contains millions of records and handling duplicates in a Python list or dictionary would simply consume too much memory.

Comment: "remove" sounds like you want to remove something, when in reality you want to make sure you do not add duplicated authors in the first place, not sure what is the efficient way for that

Comment: @python_user The key is removing duplicated authors in the database itself, and not tracking them in Python code. I don't think it's possible to avoid saving them in the database first.

Comment: why would you add duplicated authors in the database? isn't that redundant if the only column that is changing is id and 4 others are same?

Comment: @python_user The authors get added so that the DB-API itself can remove the duplicated data, and not Python. There are at least three queries: one to insert the data, one to perform an update statement to change the IDs in the many-to-many BookAuthor model, and one to delete the duplicated values in the Author model. I'm specifically looking to avoid tracking the authors in a Python data structure (e.g., a list), as the memory requirement to do so would be too high.